# Combining look aheads not matching

Tags: regex

I have the following test string I'm working with:

```
__level__:,Undergraduate,;__subject__:,Maths,Art,;
```

This is actually a stringified object of `{ level: ["Undergraduate"], subject: ["Maths", "Art"] }` that I figured converting to a string and using a regular expression might be quicker than looping through each level|subject and each value within those properties.

I can match a single value within a list of a property (e.g. level) like so:

```
(?=(__subject__:[^;]*(,Maths,).*?;))
```

And I can match two like so:

```
(?=(__subject__:[^;]*(,Maths,).*?;))(?=(__subject__:[^;]*(,Art,).*?;))
```

However, I can't guarantee the order that level and subject lists will be. Below is also possible:

```
__subject__:,Maths,Art,;__level__:,Undergraduate,;
```

Notice I've put subject before level now. Now the regular expression doesn't match. I'm pretty new to look aheads so I can't figure out what I've done wrong. Would appreciate any help on the matter.

I also want to combine the properties being matched, so something like:

```
(?=(__level__:[^;]*(,Undergraduate,).*?;))(?=(__subject__:[^;]*(,Maths,).*?;))(?=(__subject__:[^;]*(,Art,).*?;))
```

..doesn't work for me either but I'm trying to match two values from the subject property and a value from the level property. Again, I can't guarantee the order of properties (e.g. level, subject) and/or values (e.g. Maths, Art OR Art, Maths)

Comment: I think working with the object structure would be much more understandable and easy to implement than trying to write a regular expression for the stringified version - what language are you working in?

Comment: Javascript. I see. It was really for performance as I was noticing notable slow down with the object iteration. I was hoping to do a comparison between the two methods when I got this one working.

Answer (score 0):

## [Class `\[A-Z\]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) & [Positive Lookahead `(?=)`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

The targets are letters `[A-Z]+?` and to exclude the words surrounded by underscore use the positive lookahead to ensure the target is followed by a comma `(?=,)`

> ```
> /([A-Z]+?)(?=,)/gi;
> ```

---

### Demo

```js
let str = `__level__:,Undergraduate,;__subject__:,Maths,Art,;`;
let rgx = /([A-Z]+?)(?=,)/gi;
let mch = rgx.exec(str);
let res = [];
while (mch !== null) {
  res.push(mch[0]);
  mch = rgx.exec(str);
}
console.log(res.join(', '));
```